# How to access ViewChildren and ContentChildren of Component in ES5?

Tags: angular, angular2-template

[Here](http://blog.mgechev.com/2016/01/23/angular2-viewchildren-contentchildren-difference-viewproviders/) is an article which shows how to access ViewChildren and ContentChildren in TypeScript. How to access the same if Angular 2 code is written in ES5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use ng.core.ViewChildren into the queries attribute of ng.core.Component.

Here is sample:

```
var component = ng.core
    .Component({
        selector: 'comp',
        template: '...',
        (...)
        queries: {
          someProp: new ng.core.ViewChildren(someDirective)
        }
    })
    .Class({
      (...)
    });
```